# Как повторять background-image со сдвигом по оси Х?

Tags: javascript, html, css

В задании к `PSD` макету, идет бордер который с полоской и градиентом.

После 2х дней веселья, пришел к выводу что стоит попробовать сделать тут `border`, дивом с `background-image`.

Вот только незадача, градиент наложен, картинка с полосками есть, однако так как оно тонюсенькая [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждая новая строка повторения, должна отклоняться на % что бы были полоски косые, нужен какой - то `shift`, `padding / margin`. Как сделать `background` с такой картинкой что бы полоски были ровные наискось?

Comment: дайтик скриншот макета, не ясно, что вам нужно. Первой мыслью была и background-repeat: repeat-x;

Answer (score 1):

> Каждая новая строка повторения, должна отклоняться на % что бы были
>   полоски косые

Скриншот того, что хотите был бы конечно к месту, но я так понимаю что вам нужно просто блок повернуть на определённый градус? Тогда есть  к примеру CSS transform: rotate(45deg); (если только фон, то создаёте на bg конт с фоном и поворачиваете его ;) ).
Если нужно что бы **каждая последующая** была **с** немного **большим/меньшим** углом, то понадобятся клоны и капля js =)

Comment: Зачем поворачивать блок, если можно поворачивать градиент?

Comment: Потому что у него не градиент, а изображение ;)